# Install specific MongoDB in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, mongodb

Below installs 2.6.10 mongo version in Ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-server
```

I am looking to get the 2.6.13 version. How to fetch the exact version? Also how to prevent sudo apt-get update/upgrade from upgrading mongo to 3.x

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ There is also a link on the page on how to install an older version (3.0).

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB 2.6 reached [end of life](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life) at the end of October, 2016. The final release version was 2.6.12 (so there will be no 2.6.13).

To [install a specific release](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-a-specific-release-of-mongodb) you can specify the desired version, eg:

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org=2.6.12 mongodb-org-server=2.6.12 mongodb-org-shell=2.6.12 mongodb-org-mongos=2.6.12 mongodb-org-tools=2.6.12
```

You can also [pin a specific version of MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#pin-a-specific-version-of-mongodb) to prevent unintended upgrades.

For each installed package you want to pin, use a command line similar to:

```
echo "mongodb-org hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections
```

Comment: above comand gives errors

Comment: @FaizMohamedHaneef Have you followed the other instructions on the Ubuntu 2.6 install page (in particular setting up the apt sources): https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/#install-mongodb? 3.0 has different repo paths.

Comment: yes. the above steps lead to same error (fresh install)

Answer (score 0):

1) It's too new, there's no package yet, so use the source, Luke!

2) `echo <packagename> hold | dpkg --set-selections`

Comment: FYI, MongoDB 2.6 reached end of life at the end of October, 2016: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-2-6-end-of-life. The final release version was 2.6.12.